# VS Code mysql ext "removes password" settings.json

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

Was having problems logging into local SQL Server (PC SQLServer) using Visual Studio Code (VSC mysql extension) Could do so using Microsoft SQL Server Management client (MSSM) using same login credentials. Saw in logs (MSSM) that failed (VSC) login was due to incorrect password. Decided to edit `settings.json` file for my VCS client.

This connection is no longer a problem for me (see solution below) I just wanted to understand how it works. Searched but could find nothing regarding this except those having difficulties finding `settings.json`.

My solution (which brings about this question)

Opened `settings.json` in VSC MS extension. Added password between quotes (see below)

```
{
        "server": ".\\sqlexpress2",
        "database": "",
        "authenticationType": "SqlLogin",
        "user": "sa",
        "password": "temppassword1",
        "emptyPasswordInput": false,
        "savePassword": true
}
```

When I hit save the password is removed by some process?

```
{
            "server": ".\\sqlexpress2",
            "database": "",
            "authenticationType": "SqlLogin",
            "user": "sa",
            "password": "",
            "emptyPasswordInput": false,
            "savePassword": true
 }
```

However the edit worked and I can now log in to my SQL Server using VSC client. But would like to know what process removes password string from `settings.json` file on saving?

Should point out that finding `settings.json` to edit is not that straight forward.

On Windows 10 in VSC using the installed extension SQL Server(mysql) version 1.10.1. For anyone interested here is my best effort at an explanation.

1. With rectangle pad icon (left side browser frame) selected (hover shows SQL Server (Cntrl+Alt+D))
2. Use Cntrl+Shift+P to bring up Search
3. You are looking for >MS SQL:Manage Connection Profiles (select)
4. Choose Edit (brings up VS Settings page which can confuse MS user)
5. Not obvious but on top right corner there is 'turned page' icon. Hover. Open Settings (JSON)

Disclaimer: 'Where did my password go?' may be interpreted as a dumb question. Since password security is paramount. I understand the need to conceal passwords. But I don't understand how a file save process can parse out a password string? Nor do I understand that an user/editor is not provided with some notification of this having been done. It simply looks like the edit was rejected.

Comment: MySQL != SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: If you are using a MySQL extension to try and connect to SQL Server thats not going to work?

Comment: Please edit your question to fix all of the incorrect acronyms. MySQL != SQL Server. VCS != VS Code. MSSM != SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio). The [MySQL extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.vscode-mysql) is currently v0.4.0, so perhaps you're referring to the [SQL Server extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-mssql.mssql) which is currently v1.10.1?

Comment: Clearing out passwords is not a normal behaviour for the SQL Server extension. Please edit your question to include the output from `code --list-extensions` or, if on macOS, `/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code --list-extensions` because it sounds like you may have another extension that's "helping" you.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but clarification of original question. Thanks for comments input. Apologies for wrong tags in original question. VS Code extensions are: Remote - WSL 0.56.0, SQL Server (mssql) 1.10.1 & SQLTools 0.23.0

I have searched CS Code Settings for "password" no results. Briefly JSON formatting is enabled. mssql configuration, Connection profiles defined in 'User Settings' (the file original question refers to) Remote WSL (Use Shell Environment is set) SQL Tools extension uses same settings.json file as mssql extension. SQL Tools also has Autoconnect To/Auto Open Session files using settings.json Autoconnect has an "install args" field in settings.json.